# How to Sync Two Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, copy

I have two folders in my Google Drive account; `Folder 1` and `Folder 2`. I will upload a file in `Folder 1` and I want the file to be copied from `Folder 1` to `Folder 2`, but if it already exists in `Folder 2` it should not be copied. Here is the script I've got, but when it runs it always copies all the files available in `Folder 1` to `Folder 2`:

```
function copyfile() {
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  var files = source_folder.getFiles();
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var srcFile = files.next();
    var newName = srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code so that:

1. Gets a list of all the file names in the destination folder.
2. For each file to copy, it first checks whether that name is in the aforementioned list. In case that it is, it will not create a copy of it.

#### Modified code

```js
function copyfile() {
  var sourceFolderName = "Folder 1";
  var destinationFolderName = "Folder 2";
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  var files = source_folder.getFiles();
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();

  var destination_files = [];
  var fileIterator = dest_folder.getFiles()
  while (fileIterator.hasNext())
    destination_files.push(fileIterator.next().getName());

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var srcFile = files.next();
    var newName = srcFile.getName();
    if (destination_files.indexOf(newName) == -1) {
      srcFile.makeCopy(dest_folder);
    }
  }
}
```